# How to stop XP_cmdshell (kill/Rollback)

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I observed that xp_cmdshell is in KILLED/ROLLBACK state in my SQL server and consuming memory from tempdb.

I tried to get the PID for this session id and the source server from which it was generated, I could not find the PID in source server tasklist.

Is there any way to stop this xp_cmdshell without restarting SQL server.

Comment: SQL server, does that mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: yes MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

In windows, XP_CMDSHELL creates a new dependent CMD process on the machine where SQL Server is installed (not on the machine from where XP_CMDSHELL is triggered, It can be triggered from a remote machine using SSMS).

You will find a process with `user name` as `MSSQLSERVER` in task manager on that machine. You got to end this process as well.

[image]

Comment: "You will find a process with user name as MSSQLSERVER in task manager on that machine. You got to end this process as well."    Could not find any such task

Comment: @Krishna508, just confirming if you checked the process in the Machine where the Database server is installed?

Comment: Yes I checked the process in the Machine where the Database server is installed.

Comment: Currently, XP_cmdshell total elapsed time in my SQL server is -50372673..... Why is it showing in -ve ??